# ASP.NET MVC showing a hidden div after form submission if object already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which a user can create a `Project`, and the model validates on `[HttpPost]` just fine.

The following validation from my `Create` Action is what I'm currently using:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var alreadyExists = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == project.Name) ?? db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID== project.ID);

    if (alreadyExists != null) // If a project with the same name exists
    {
        return View(project);
    }

    db.Projects.Add(project);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(project);
}
```

Currently if the project `Name` or `ID` already exists, it just returns the row with those values from Entity Framework with no notification to the user. I'd like to create some form of alert that tells the user, *after POST*, that the project they've tried to create already exists.

I wrote a `PartialView` and put the code in `_Create.cshtml`:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Error!</strong> A project with that name or ID already exists!
</div>
```

And the following at the top of my form in `Create.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", Model)
```

and updated my `Create` controller to return the `PartialView`:

```
var alreadyExists = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == project.Name) ?? db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.TAF == project.TAF);

if (alreadyExists != null) // If a project with the same name exists
{
    return PartialView(project);
}
```

But the bootstrap alert is always showing, even before POSTing the form to the controller.

How can I make the alert show only after a POST if the EF database already contains a record with the same properties?

Comment: You can just add a `ModelState` error and it will be displayed in your view's `@Html.ValidationSummary()` (you might also want to consider using a `RemoteAttribute` so you get client side validation

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError(...)` & `Html.ValidationSummary()` helper is enough, they're appear depending on what validation error you have. Consider hiding the element using `jQuery.hide()` in first place if insisted to use bootstrap `div`.

Comment: Ah, `ModelStateError` did the trick, thanks. Feel free to write it up as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a `ViewBag` property in the POST method to indicate if there was an error, for example `ViewBag.Error = true;` and then in the view, test if it exists

```
@if(ViewBag.HasError != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Create", Model)
}
```

Howevere, MVC already has this functionality built in. In the POST method, you can add a `ModelState` error

```
if (alreadyExists != null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "your error message");
}
```

and that message will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` placeholder in your view.

Note that if your want the message associated with a specific property, you can use `ModelState.AddModelError("YourPropertyName", "your error message");` and it will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YOurPropertyName)`

You can also consider using the `RemoteAttribute` to give you client side validation - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)